# How to count nodes in XML that have been read into a string

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml, nodes

I'm sure the solution is pretty trivial to the experienced, but it's not to me. I have read an XML file into a string, strSiteList. Here's a shortened sample of the XML:

```
<siteList>
  <site code="s0000001">
    <nameEn>Edmonton</nameEn>
    <provinceCode>AB</provinceCode>
  </site>
  <site code="s0000002">
    <nameEn>Vancouver</nameEn>
    <provinceCode>BC</provinceCode>
  </site>
</siteList>
```

How do I count the number of times a site appears?
I've started with this:

```
XDocument loaded = XDocument.Parse(strSiteList);
int sitesCount = loaded.Nodes().Count(d => "some code that should work...arg...";
```

But I am lost as to whether it's the right way to start this or not.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this C# you are using? Why do you read it as a string?! C# has many better ways to represent a XML document in memory and then you can simply use LINQ to extract whatever information you want!

Comment: @FailedDev: He's already parsing it into LINQ to XML. It's not like he's trying to do this with a regex... now yes, using `XDocument.Load` might make more sense, but that's irrelevant to how he's doing the searching.

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry I didn't read through or tested it. I though he stored it into a string.

Comment: do you want to find out how many <site> element there are or how many <site> elements with the same code?

Comment: Hi, It's in C#. I'm trying to find out the number of <site> elements (as an intermediate step). I'll have about 1000 of them. I read the XML from the web and stored it as a string.  I'm trying to load an XML file into a matrix array so I can display a form for user input. If I'm going about this wrong, I can correct it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A particular site? That sounds to me like:

```
string site = "s0000002";
XDocument loaded = XDocument.Parse(xml);
int sitesCount = loaded.Descendants("site")
                       .Count(x => (string) x.Attribute("code") == site);
```

For *all* sites, just:

```
int sitesCount = loaded.Descendants("site").Count();
```

Comment: Thanks, it was for all sites. It was pretty trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple XPath expression (using "System.Xml.XPath" required):

```
XDocument loaded = XDocument.Parse(xml);
int sitesCount = loaded.XPathSelectElements("siteList/site").Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it's been read in correctly, you should be able to do this:

```
int sitesCount = loaded.Descendants("site").Where(x => x.Attribute("code").Value == "1234").Count();
```

You can also do this:

```
int sitesCount = loaded.Descendants("site").Count(x => x.Attribute("code").Value == "1234");
```

If you're looking for a count of all the sites, you can just do this:

```
int sitesCount = loaded.Descendants("site").Count();
```